# how do you install pexpect on Eclipse with the pydev plugin?

Tags: eclipse, installation, pydev, pexpect

I opened cmd and typed in 'pip install pexpect' and I have confirmation that it installed. However when I use eclipse, it does not recognize pexpect. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use **$easy_install --user pexpect** in your terminal.http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html